# Test Grunt Tasks

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, yeoman

I am using Yeoman to generate some projects and also grunt-tasks.
Now I would also like to test the generated grunt tasks using Mocha, but I only find some information how to use Mocha tests in Grunt ;-)

Can anybody help?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly that you *cannot* do? Grunt tasks are often invoked at the command line. Mocha tests can be used to test command line tools. Your Grunt tasks are generated by Yeoman. Presumably, these are text files. A Mocha test can read a text file and check that it is as expected. So what is it you can't do, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but I took the approach of installing my dependencies (`npm install`) and consequently running the corresponding grunt task (for e.g. `grunt less`) and then writing test logic post that operation. I've used nested [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) calls for this.

```
describe('less grunt tasks tests', function () {
    var prompts = {
      workFolder: 'temp',
      fiddleDesc: 'mocha test'
    };
    var testGlobal = {};
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      testGlobal.app = helpers.run(path.join(__dirname, '../app'))
        .inTmpDir(function(dir, err) {
          if(err) { done(err); return; }
          testGlobal.dir = dir;
          // console.log(dir);
        })
        .withArguments(['skip-install'])
        .withOptions({ less: true })
        .withPrompts(prompts)
        .on('end', function(){
          done();
        });
    });

    it('should modify app/styles/style.css', function(done){
      this.timeout(60000 * 10); //10 minutes - my network is f**ked up
      var opts = {
        cwd : testGlobal.dir,
        env: process.env,
        detached: true
      };
      var gen = testGlobal.app.generator;
      var devdeps = gen.devDependencies.join(' ');
      var rootPath = testGlobal.dir;
      var getPath = function(fpath) {
        var s = path.join(rootPath, fpath);
        // console.log(s); ;
        return s;
      };

      exec('npm install ' + devdeps, opts, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        if(err) {
          done(err);
          return;
        }

        var h1 = fs.readFileSync(getPath('app/less/h1.less'), 'utf8');
        var css = fs.readFileSync(getPath('app/styles/style.css'), 'utf8');
        // expect(css).to.not.contain(h1);
        expect(css).to.not.contain('h1');

        exec('grunt less', opts, function(e, out, serr){
          if(e) {
            done(e);
            return;
          }
          // console.log(out);

          var h1 = fs.readFileSync(getPath('app/less/h1.less'), 'utf8');
          var css = fs.readFileSync(getPath('app/styles/style.css'), 'utf8');
          // expect(css).to.contain(h1); //this expect fails since for some reason \r are stripped out
          expect(css).to.contain('h1');
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

For more reference you can see more test code in the [repo](https://github.com/behrangsa/generator-fiddle/blob/develop/test/test-less.js#L91) I contribute against.

Ps: I'd appreciate your comments on the approach I've taken.